# Private Static Dependency vs Private Dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

```
  public interface ISomeDependency
  {
    void Calculate( Person person );
  }
  public class SomeDependency : ISomeDependency
  {
    void ISomeDependency.Calculate( Person person )
    {          
      person.Age = 30;
    }
  }

  public class Person
  {
    private static ISomeDependency _someDependency;
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Person( ISomeDependency someDependency )
    {
      _someDependency = someDependency;
    }
    public void CalculateAge()
    {
      _someDependency.Calculate( this );
    }
  }
  public class Client
  {
    public Client()
    {
      Person p = new Person( new SomeDependency() );
      p.BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears( -30 );
      p.CalculateAge();
    }
  }
```

Why would it matter if the dependency is static or not?  In general, does it matter?

Comment: That would depend on whether all `Person` objects share the same implementation of the dependency or not. If they do, perhaps it should be static, but IMO, it should not be passed to the constructor of `Person`, as that implies that it is non-static.

Comment: Injecting a static field doesn't make a lot of sense unless you can guarantee only a single instance (Singleton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would it matter if the dependency is static or not? In general, does it matter?

Yes - in your case you have an instance constructor that's resetting the static member, so the value of the static member will be the value that *the last constructor was given*.

Since there's no reason to make the dependency static that I can see (you have no static methods/properties that use it) it should be fine an an instance (non-static) field.

Comment: I would add that it's not thread-safe either. Construction of an object should not have an impact on the thread safety of other instances of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

if _someDependency is static ,it will get stored in high frequency heap else it will goto low frequency heap.